# image scroll on hover

Tags: views

I'm not necessarily looking for a module for this, but I'm curious where to start to get the following functionality:

Each content entity has an unlimited amount of image fields. So if I had 5 images I want to be able to "scroll" through them on the frontpage. The scrolling functionality is that when you hover over the image, it shows different images. The frontpage is generated by a view

I'm basically making a TV show site with screenshots and I want the user to be able to preview some screenshots on the frontpage by simply hovering over the episode image.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a slideshow for each content, based on that image field. There are many modules that offer that functionality, some themes, and you can always write or otherwise incorporate Javascript to handle it for you.